# can a markdown string be assigned to the body of an email using code c#

Tags: azure, outlook, markdown, powerapps, o365-flow

Can a markdown string (table) be assigned to the body of an email using code? c#
If not how can I assign markdown to render in an email body programmatically?

I'm using an Azure "Logic apps' O365 send email action

example markdown table:

```
**Payment Approval Request by:** Brian Pem\n\n| | |\n|--------------|-----------|\n| **Group:** | 39850 |\n| **Approval Email GL:** | 06350 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook is not aware about the markdown markup. You need to translate the markdown markup into HTML code and then assign to the message body.